# Rally App onLoad

Tags: extjs, rally

I have a Rally app that requires considerable loading time and it has some loops containing Data Stores. I need to find a condition where the app has completed loading. Once the execution of the app is complete, I want to refresh my page. Is there something like onLoad() that I can use to notify that the app has loaded completely and then I could add `window.location.reload` at the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using either a callback function, for a single data store, or a series of promises for multiple data stores. The former is pretty straight forward but this is how I usually handle the latter:

In this case, I'm simultaneously loading all the User Stories, Defects and Test Cases in the current scope, then when *all* the records have been loaded successfully, the "success" function will be called.

```
launch: function() {
    Deft.Promise.all([
        this.loadRecords('UserStory'),
        this.loadRecords('Defect'),
        this.loadRecords('TestCase')
    ]).then({
        success: function(recordSets) {
            // recordSets = [
            //  UserStoryRecords,
            //  DefectRecords,
            //  TestCaseRecords
            // ];
        },
        failure: function() {
            //Handle error loading the store here...
        }
    });
},

loadRecords: function(model) {
    var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        limit : Infinity,
        model : model,
        fetch : ['Name','ObjectID']
    }).load({
        callback : function(records, operation, success) {
            if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                deferred.resolve(records);
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply , I have a chained link of data stores in which I pass the result from one data store to the next one, it has to be done in a synchronous manner. The first data store is inside a for loop. I want the end() function to be called when the for loop has executed completely. But it's not working that way.

Comment: I used `Deft.Promise.all` to load the stores in parrallel but you could just as easily do this serially. Since you are passing one store result to another, I'd look into the docs for `Deft.Chain.pipeline`. http://docs.deftjs.org/deft-js/0-8-0/#!/api/Deft.promise.Chain-method-pipeline